# Nested Tables and List Plot

Tags: plotting

Take two matrices which depends on three parameters i1,i2 and i3

```
m1 = {{i1, 0, 0}, {0, i2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
m2 = {{0, i1, 0}, {0, i2, 0}, {0, 0, i3}}
```

I am using a function defined as

```
NT[n_] := Module[{n1 = n},
  Table[Table[Eigenvalues[n1], {i1, 0, 1, 0.2}], {i2, 0, 0.2, 
    0.1}, {i3, 0, 0.3, 0.1}]
]
```

(*(But I need to plot the value of the factor (NT[m1])^2-NT[m2]))^2 
with all combinations of the values of the parameters i2 and i3*)
In all the Plots the Value of the parameter appear along the X-Axis.
(*I am able to find out the numerical values of the factor 
(NT[m1])^2-(NT[m2])^2 as given below, but how to make,list plot of \
this factor with all the combinations of the parameter values i2 and 
i3*)

I tried the following code

```
NT[n_] := Module[{n1 = n},
  Table[ListLinePlot[Table[Eigenvalues[n1], {i1, 0, 1, 0.2}], 
    PlotLabel -> Row@{"i2=", i2, "i3=", i3}], {i2, 0, 0.2, 0.1}, {i3, 
    0, 0.3, 0.1}]
  ]
```

but do not calculate the factor (NT[m1])^2-NT[m2]))^2

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: The styling of your question can be improved. Please take the time to read the [markdown help page](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You'll better communicate your problem when you use the right formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly speaking, your question is not very clear. I put this answer based on what I understand

```
nt[i1_, i2_, i3_] := Module[{m1, m2, ev1, ev2},
   m1 = {{i1, 0, 0}, {0, i2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}; 
   m2 = {{0, i1, 0}, {0, i2, 0}, {0, 0, i3}};
   ev1 = Sort@Eigenvalues[m1];
   ev2 = Sort@Eigenvalues[m2];
  (ev1[[#]]^2 - ev2[[#]]^2) & /@ Range[Length[ev1]]
  ] 

Table[
  dat = Table[{i, nt[i, j, k]}, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}];
  ListLinePlot[Table[{#[[1]], #[[2, i]]} & /@ dat, {i, 3}], 
   Frame -> True,FrameLabel -> {"i1", None}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row@{"i2=", j, "i3=", k}]
,{j, 0, 1, 0.5}, {k, 0, 1, 0.5}] // Grid
```

[image]